# Is the intersection of a normal group N of G with a subgroup H a normal group of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was given this question in a test and i could not solve it. To the point where im beggining to doubt it is true. The question is as follows: Let G be a group. N a normal sub group of G and H a subgroup of G contained in N. Then $N \cap H$ is normal in G.

Comment: contained in $N$, maybe?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is false.
Consider the case when your $G=S_4\;\;,$
$N=K_4\;\;$={$I, (1 2)(3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (14)(2 3)$} H={$(1 2)(3 4)$}
Clearly you can see $N$ is normal in $G$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ contained in $N$. And $H$ intersection $N$ is again $H$.
Is H normal in G?.No, you can verify.

Comment: I knew it!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We have $N\unlhd G$, $H\le G$ and $H\subseteq N$. 
First note, that this is just a consequence of the second isomorphism theorem.

**Proof:** It is easy to show, that the kernel of an homomorphism is a normal subgroup. Consider the homomorphism $\varphi:H\to HN\to HN/N$, which maps $h\mapsto h N$. 
$$\ker(\varphi)=\{h\in H|hN=N\}=\{h\in H|h\in N\}=H\cap N\unlhd H.$$

**EDIT:** The OP wanted to know, if $H\cap N\unlhd G$, not $H\cap N\unlhd H$.

Obviously $H\cap N\unlhd G$ is wrong. Just take $G:=S_4$. $N:=V_4=\{id, (1 2) (3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3) \}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. $H:=\{id, (12)(34)\}\le G$ and $H\subseteq N$. But $\{id,(12)(34)\}$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: The question was about the normality of $N\cap H$ in $G$, not in $H$.